# What is the range of ambient temperature I can keep my espresso machine at?

Tags: espresso-machine

**Background**

I have a Rocket R58 and I'm twondering if it would be safe to keep it in a low temperature place like a garage. Let's say that would be something like 12C. I've had a look around at both the manual for my machine and several others but I can't see any instructions beyond guidance around storage temperature.

For that they mention that it's important to not let it freeze which is sensible and pretty obvious. I've also had a search around google but can't find anything around operating temperatures.

**Question**

Do any coffee machines have explictly stated safe operating temperature ranges and if so what are they? If this isn't common, have any of you used espresso machines in colder environments longer term and are there any issue involved / is there anything I should look out for?

Answer (score 1):

Any coffe machine is quite broad. I suggest considering the materials involved. Since portafilter machines are meant to operate on higher than ambient temperatures for a very long time, lower temps aren't usually a problem in terms of degradation.

I can't remember any materials involved in a portafilter machine that would degrade faster (or et damaged) in lower temperatures rather than operating temperatures.

Dependig on the age, there might be hemp sealings in the machine that could potentially dry out.